# Use polymorphic association to determine ownership? Or should I leave an empty column on the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have been working on a problem and can't decide whether the solution calls for polymorphic association or simply having an empty column on my table.

Let's say I'm making a fundraising website and donations can be made as an individual or as a collective. My website won't distinguish between collective and individual user accounts; user's can organize themselves into collectives and make decisions about donating money based on consensus or give freely on their own if they choose.

So I have my Gift, User, and Collective models, and a Membership join-table model.

A collective has many memberships, and many users through memberships; a user (may) have many memberships, and many collectives through memberships; and a gift should either belong to a user or a collective. This is where I get confused.

My first approach was to create a polymorphic association with a Donation class

```
class Donations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :donor, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :gift
end
```

with the table on the schema looking like:

```
create_table "donations" do |t|
  t.integer "donor_id"
  t.string "donor_type"
  t.integer "gift_id"
end
```

which would mean my Collective class would look like:

```
class Collective < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :donations, as: :donor
  has_many :gifts, through: :donations 
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
 end
```

and my User class would look like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :donations, as: :donor
  has_many :gifts, through: :donations 
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :collectives, through: :memberships
 end
```

but when I'm making my Gifts class, what is it supposed to belong to?

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :donor #???
  ##has_one :donor, through: :donation??
end
```

From research, it seems polymorphic associations are usually used for more minute features like notes or comments. The object is usually already clearly owned, and the owned object is usually being affiliated with something that usually has a many-to-many relationship.

I'm wondering if it would simply be easier to have two columns in my database, leaving one blank via a validation depending on whether the donation was made by a collective or individual. Or, is this potentially a good example of the usefulness of polymorphic associations?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm, I seem to have found something here: https://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/02/10/rails-polymorphic-models/

Comment: you probably don't need a donation class.  gift and donation is a 1-1 association right?  If you think you need it, just add a `has_one :donation` and `has_one :donor, through: :donation` in the Gift class.

Comment: I see what you're saying...but I'm trying to have two donor categories. The donor could either be an individual, or a collective group using one id.

Comment: I don't see a need to specify the difference between a donation that has one or many users associated with it via a Collective model. Although, it could be done that way. You could simply use the User model and set nested attributes for both users and gifts on the Donation model.

Comment: That's true, I suppose I want the Collective model to have more functionality in other parts of my site, rather than simply being a group of individuals nested in a hash in the User class.

Comment: @jvnill ah yes i see your second example is correct thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so it turns out this way does work. I'll simplify what I learned from following along in the article I linked in a previous comment.

My model looks like this:

```
class Donation < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :donor, polymorphic: true
 belongs_to :gift
end
```

Now, we have to create a new instance of Donation. Here's how I assigned them:

```
soccer_team = Collective.new(name: "Hamilton High Soccer Team")

tony = User.new(name: "Tony")

christmas_from_tony = Gift.new
christmas_from_soccer_team = Gift.new

christmas_donation_from_tony = Donation.new(donor_id: tony.id, donor_type: tony.class.name, gift_id: christmas_from_tony.id)
christmas_donation_from_soccer_team = Donation.new(donor_id: soccer_team.id, donor:type: soccer_team.class.name, gift_id: christmas_from_soccer_team.id)
```

So now I can call

```
tony.donations.first.gift

girlscouts.donations.first.gift
```

and get each individual gift instance!

Not exactly sure when I'll use "donor" yet in this case, because a gift will always have only one donor.

But I got it to work for what I wanted!